# Why does my Perl unit test for a CGI program fail all its tests?

Tags: perl, testing, command, cgi

i would like to test a little program in perl .cgi

this program is at this url:

https://perlmaven.com/testing-perl-cgi

this program is a general test and he say:

"it is enough to show how to test any CGI-script"

then i copy/paste the 2 cgi in the same directory and try the command line:

```
prove cgi.t
```

normally all successfull

the error is:

```
     Failed test 'GET'
    #   at cgi.t line 20.
    #                   ''
    #     doesn't match '(?^:<tr><td>request_method</td><td>GET</td></tr>)'

    #   Failed test 'name'
    #   at cgi.t line 21.
    #                   ''
    #     doesn't match '(?^:<tr><td>name</td><td>foo</td></tr>)'

    #   Failed test 'email'
    #   at cgi.t line 22.
    #                   ''
    #     doesn't match '(?^:<tr><td>email</td><td>bar\@corp.com</td></tr>)'

    #   Failed test 'stderr is empty'
    #   at cgi.t line 23.
    #          got: 'Can't exec "./cgi.pl": Permission denied at cgi.t line 17.
    # '
    #     expected: ''

    #   Failed test 'exit code is 0'
    #   at cgi.t line 24.
    #          got: '-1'
    #     expected: '0'
    # Looks like you failed 5 tests of 5.
cgi.t .. 1/2
#   Failed test 'get'
#   at cgi.t line 25.

    #   Failed test 'POST'
    #   at cgi.t line 43.
    #                   ''
    #     doesn't match '(?^:<tr><td>request_method</td><td>POST</td></tr>)'

    #   Failed test 'language'
    #   at cgi.t line 44.
    #                   ''
    #     doesn't match '(?^:<tr><td>language</td><td>Perl</td></tr>)'

    #   Failed test 'creator'
    #   at cgi.t line 45.
    #                   ''
    #     doesn't match '(?^:<tr><td>creator</td><td>TimToady</td></tr>)'

    #   Failed test 'stderr is empty'
    #   at cgi.t line 46.
    #          got: 'sh: ./cgi.pl: Permission denied
    # '
    #     expected: ''

    #   Failed test 'exit code is 0'
    #   at cgi.t line 47.
    #          got: '32256'
    #     expected: '0'
    # Looks like you failed 5 tests of 5.

#   Failed test 'post'
#   at cgi.t line 48.
# Looks like you failed 2 tests of 2.
cgi.t .. Dubious, test returned 2 (wstat 512, 0x200)
Failed 2/2 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
cgi.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 2 Failed: 2)
  Failed tests:  1-2
  Non-zero exit status: 2
Files=1, Tests=2,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.12 usr  0.01 sys +  0.44 cusr  0.06 csys                                                                                                                                                              =  0.63 CPU)
Result: FAIL
```

Thanks in advance,

Ornot

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As James says, if you contact Gabor directly he will probably explain it to you. But let's see what else we can do for you here.

Comment: One of the failures is because your *cgi.pl* file isn't marked as executable. `chmod +x cgi.pl` should fix that one.

Comment: @Shawn good call. It's not Windows like I assumed. My error is different. Meh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just happen to be booted into my Windows right now, and I see a similiar failure.

The problem is very hard to spot for a beginner, but really very simple.

> ```
> my ($out, $err, $exit) = capture { system "./cgi.pl" };
> ```

The way that the program is called is clearly very Linux-y. If you change that to say `perl cgi.pl` it will work. This is because the `./` part of the command tells the Linux shell to run the program `cgi.pl` in the current directory. It does that by looking for the file, seeing whether it has the executable flag, and then looks in the first line of the file. There, it finds the [*shebang*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (`#!/usr/bin/perl`), which tells it what program to run the file with.

On Windows, it doesn't work like that, so you need to call the `perl` executable directly. In your case however, it's because **the file is not executable**.

You can just change it like I said above, or you can set the executable flag on your program. Run this in the command line. It will mark your program as executable, and the OS will know what to do.

```
$ chmod u+x cgi.pl
```

If you go with the code change, remember you need to change it in two places.

---

You *could have* infered that from the test output. One of the failing tests shows us the return value for `$err`, which is the STDERR output channel of the command.

> ```
> #   Failed test 'stderr is empty'
> #   at cgi.t line 23.
> #          got: 'Can't exec "./cgi.pl": Permission denied at cgi.t line 17.
> # '
> #     expected: ''
> ```

But it takes a lot of experience to actually not be frustrated by so much failing test output to actually read the whole thing and on top of it understand what it could mean. For what it's worth, I didn't read it all either. I glanced over the test output to see I get the same, then read the code and spotted the `./cgi.pl`, which made me wonder. For some reason I also remembered I am right now on Windows. Probably because it was hard work to run it in the first place.

Comment: On a side-note, you might want to use this opportunity to install a virtual machine, possibly Virtual Box, and try around with Linux. Installing a fresh Ubuntu is very easy, and it will give you some practice on that as well. You also might want to not do CGI for new projects. I recommend [this talk by Sawyer X](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jKOqtRMT85), which is a humorous take on a very serious matter. This stuff is old, and really not a lot of fun to work with. Do something more modern instead and enjoy working with Perl. It's great. :)

Comment: Re "*On Windows, it doesn't work like that, so you need to call the perl executable directly.*", Or create a file association

Answer (score 1):

Now all command line are succesfully with the solution of @simbabque

```
perl cgi.t
```

1..2

## Subtest: get

```
1..5
ok 1 - GET
ok 2 - name
ok 3 - email
ok 4 - stderr is empty
ok 5 - exit code is 0
```

ok 1 - get

## Subtest: post

```
1..5
ok 1 - POST
ok 2 - language
ok 3 - creator
ok 4 - stderr is empty
ok 5 - exit code is 0
```

ok 2 - post

and with this command:

```
prove cgi.t
```

cgi.t .. ok

All tests successful.

Files=1, Tests=2,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.11 usr  0.02 sys +  0.64 cusr  0.08 csys =  0.85 CPU)

Result: PASS